# Form failure: $(...).jsGrid is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Insert products and specifications</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous" />  <!-- We include Bootstrap from a CDN (Content Delivery Network). -->
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="jsgrid.min.css" />                                       <!-- We point to the external css stylesheet file named "jsgrid.min.css". -->
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="jsgrid-theme.min.css" />                                     <!-- We point to the external css stylesheet file named "jsgrid-theme.min.css". -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>                <!-- We get the complete "script" tag including Subresource "Integrity" attribute from the jQuery CDN domain. -->  
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jsgrid.min.js"></script>                                        <!-- We point to the external script file named "jsgrid.min.js". -->
  </head>
```

I decided to apply a **jQuery plugin** named **jsGrid** in order to **create a grid for my HTML Table** but for some reason when I load my html form, I take this error message: **Form failure: $(...).jsGrid is not a function**.

I followed exactly the **Getting started steps** of this site: 
http://js-grid.com/getting-started/

*My **code***:

```js
<script cam-script type="text/form-script">
       var product = $scope.product = [];                                                                  // Custom JavaScript creates a JavaScript Object and binds it to the current AngularJS $scope of the form as a variable named "product".
       $scope.addProduct = function () {                                                                   // We make a function named "addProduct".
         var product = {};                                                                        // We add a new "product" to the Array.
         product.Category = $scope.Category;
         product.Description = $scope.Description;
         if (!!$scope.camForm.fields[0].element[0].files[0]) {                                                        // If the file is uploaded,
           product.Details = $scope.camForm.fields[0].element[0].files[0].name;                                                // it returns file's "name".
         } else {                                                                            // If the file is not uploaded,
           return;                                                                           // it returns "undefined".
         }
         product.Price = $scope.Price;
         $scope.product.push(product);                                                                   // We use the value of the "product" input field to add a new "product" to the Array.
         $scope.Category = "";                                                                      // We clear the TextBox "Κατηγορία".
         $scope.Description = "";                                                                     // We clear the TextBox "Περιγραφή".
         $scope.Details = "";                                                                      // We clear file's "name".
         $scope.Price = "";                                                                        // We clear the TextBox "Τιμή (€)".
       };
    $scope.clear = function () {                                             // We make a function named "clear".
     angular.element("input[type='file']").val(null);
    };
       $scope.removeProduct = function (index) {                                                               // We make a function named "removeProduct".
         var category = $scope.product[index].Category;                                                           // We find product's "Category" using "index" from the Array and binds it to the current AngularJS $scope of the form as a variable named "category".
         $scope.product.splice(index, 1);                                                                 // We use an "index" to remove a "product" from the Array.
       }
       $scope.isAddFormValid = function () {                                                                 // We make a function named "isAddFormValid".
         return ($scope.Category &&
               $scope.Description &&
             $scope.camForm.fields[0].element[0].files[0] &&
             $scope.Price) ? true : false;                                                               // If all of the 4 input fields of variable "product" are filled in, the "isAddFormValid" function (expression) returns "true", otherwise the function returns "false".
       }
       camForm.on('form-loaded', function() {                                                                 // We hook into the lifecycle of Camunda SDK JS Form.
         camForm.variableManager.createVariable ({                                                             // We "create" (declare) a new "process" variable
           name:'product',                                                                       // named 'product' and
           type:'json',                                                                        // provide as type information 'json' used for serialization.
           value:product
         });
       });
       camForm.on('submit', function(evt) {                                                                 // We hook into the lifecycle of Camunda SDK JS Form.
         if (product.length<1) {                                                                      // If no any "product" is added,
           evt.submitPrevented = true;                                                                  // an event handler prevents the form from being submitted by setting the property "submitPrevented" to 'true'.
         }
       });
    var category = [
     { Name: "", Id: 0 },
     { Name: "Desktop", Id: 1 },
     { Name: "Laptop",  Id: 2 },
     { Name: "Tablet",  Id: 3 },
     { Name: "Οθόνη Υπολογιστή", Id: 4 },
     { Name: "Οθόνη Προβολής", Id: 5 },
     { Name: "Εκτυπωτής laser", Id: 6 },
     { Name: "Φωτοτυπικό Μηχάνημα", Id: 7 },
     { Name: "Scanner", Id: 8 },
     { Name: "UPS", Id: 9 },
     { Name: "Διαδικτυακή Συσκευή Αποθήκευσης", Id: 10 },
     { Name: "Εξωτερικός Σκληρός Δίσκος", Id: 11 },
     { Name: "Προτζέκτορας", Id: 12 },
     { Name: "Βιντεοπροτζέκτορας", Id: 13 }
    ];

    $("#jsGrid").jsGrid({
     width: "100%",
     height: "400px",

     inserting: true,
     editing: true,
     sorting: true,
     paging: true,

     data: product,
     
     fields: [
      { name: "Κατηγορία", type: "select", items: category, valueField: "Id", textField: "Name" },
      { name: "Περιγραφή", type: "text" },
      { name: "Λεπτομέρειες", type: "text" },
      { name: "Τιμή (€)", type: "number", width: 75 },
      { type: "control" }
     ]    
    });
      </script>
```

```html
<h2><b>Λίστα Προϊόντων</b></h2>                                                                      <!-- We set the heading of the HTML Table. -->
      <div id="jsGrid">                                                 <!-- We add a "<div>" for the grid. -->
       <table style="width:100%;">
         <thead>                                                                             <!-- We group the "header" content in the HTML Table. -->
           <tr>                                                                            <!-- The "header" content of the HTML Table is not repeated. -->
             <th>Κατηγορία</th>
             <th>Περιγραφή</th>
             <th>Λεπτομέρειες</th>
             <th style="width:75px;">Τιμή (€)</th>
             <th></th>
           </tr>
         </thead>
         <tbody ng-repeat="x in product track by $index">                                                          <!-- The HTML Table is populated from the JSON Array "product", using a "ng-repeat" directive which is assigned to each row of the Table in order to repeat all the objects of the Array. -->
           <tr>                                                                            <!-- Each row of the HTML Table consists of 4 HTML fields and 1 button. -->
             <td><input type="text" value="{{x.Category}}" /></td>
             <td style="width:100%; padding:0px 8px 0px 0px"><input  style="width:100%;" type="text" value="{{x.Description}}" /></td>
             <td><input type="text" value="{{x.Details}}" /></td>
             <td><input style="width:75px;" type="number" value="{{x.Price}}" /></td>
             <td><input type="button" ng-click="removeProduct($index)" value="Remove" /></td>                                         <!-- The "ng-click" directive is assigned to the "Remove" button and calls the function named "removeProduct" with the current "$index" when this button is clicked. -->
           </tr>
         </tbody>
       </table>
      </div>
      <hr>                                                                                 <!-- We separate the HTML content of the page. -->
      <div>
       <h2><b>Καταχώρησε νέο προϊόν</b></h2>                                                                 <!-- We set the heading of the HTML Form. -->
       <div class="row">                                                                          <!-- We set the "1st row" of the HTML Form. -->
         <div class="col-md-6">                                                                      <!-- We use "md" for "medium" screen devices of width "equal to or greater than" 992px and "6" for adding 6 columns. -->
           <div class="form-group">                                                                   <!-- We use "form-group" for optimum spacing. -->
             <label class="control-label" for="category">Επίλεξε Κατηγορία:</label>
             <div class="controls">
              <input list="category" name="categories" ng-model="Category" />                                   <!-- When the value of the input field "Επίλεξε Κατηγορία" changes, is bound to the created variable "Category" in AngularJS by the "ng-model" directive. -->
        <datalist id="category">
         <option value="Desktop">
         <option value="Laptop">
         <option value="Tablet">
         <option value="Οθόνη Υπολογιστή">
         <option value="Οθόνη Προβολής">
         <option value="Εκτυπωτής laser">
         <option value="Φωτοτυπικό Μηχάνημα">
         <option value="Scanner">
         <option value="UPS">
         <option value="Διαδικτυακή Συσκευή Αποθήκευσης">
         <option value="Εξωτερικός Σκληρός Δίσκος">
         <option value="Προτζέκτορας">
         <option value="Βιντεοπροτζέκτορας">
        </datalist> 
             </div>
           </div>
         </div>
         <div class="col-md-6">
           <div class="form-group">
             <label class="control-label" for="description">Περιγραφή</label>
             <div class="controls">
              <input id="description" type="text" onkeypress="this.style.width = ((this.value.length + 1) * 8) + 'px';" ng-model="Description" />                 <!-- When the value of the input field "Περιγραφή" changes, is bound to the created variable "Description" in AngularJS by the "ng-model" directive. -->
             </div>
           </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                         <label class="control-label" for="details">Λεπτομέρειες</label>
                            <div class="controls">
                             <input id="details"
                                       type="file"
                                       cam-variable-name="Details"
                                       cam-variable-type="File"
                                       cam-max-filesize="10000000" ng-model="Details" />                                                                                              <!-- When the value of the input field "Λεπτομέρειες" changes, is bound to the created variable "Details" in AngularJS by the "ng-model" directive. -->
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                         <label class="control-label" for="price">Τιμή (€)</label>
                            <div class="controls">
                             <input style="width:75px;" id="price" type="number" min="0" ng-model="Price" />                                                                       <!-- When the value of the input field "Τιμή (€)" changes, is bound to the created variable "Price" in AngularJS by the "ng-model" directive. -->
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="controls">
                         <input type="button" ng-click="addProduct();clear()" ng-show="isAddFormValid()" value="Add" />                                                                  <!-- The "ng-show" directive shows the input element ("Add" button) only if the "isAddFormValid()" function (expression) returns "true". The "ng-click" directive is assigned to the "Add" button and calls the functions named "addProduct()" and "clear()" when this button is clicked. -->
                        </div>
         </div>
       </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Does anyone know please why do I take this **error message**?

Thanks,
Steve

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have not embedded the source itself inside your document:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jsgrid/1.5.3/jsgrid.min.css" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jsgrid/1.5.3/jsgrid-theme.min.css" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jsgrid/1.5.3/jsgrid.min.js"></script>
```

did you embed these before the execution of you code starts?

Comment: I have just added the meta data of my head section in my post here above. If you could please take a look I'd appreciate that. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Looks like your are trying to embed from your local server `<script type="text/javascript" src="jsgrid.min.js"></script>`. Is the file in the same folder as your html file? If not, try to use a cdn (Content Delivery Network) like I did in my answer (just copy the `<script>` tag from my answer) and replace `<script type="text/javascript" src="jsgrid.min.js"></script>` with it).

Comment: Yes, I call my html file from a local server (Apache Tomcat). This "js file" is in the same folder as my "html file" in my Eclipse. If you take a look above, you can see that I got the complete "script tag" from the jQuery CDN domain.